# Linux system information c++ vs bash vs python

Tags: python, c++, linux, bash

I would like to make a program to read information from `/proc` on Linux systems, as light and fast as possible.

My initial question is which programming language should I use?

At the moment:

- bash
- C++ (never used before)
- python

So I wrote a simple benchmark: read `/proc/loadavg` and return the first 3 values:

- **loadavg.sh**

```sh
awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' /proc/loadavg
```

- **loadavg.cpp**

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream rawavg("/proc/loadavg");
    if(rawavg) {
        std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(rawavg),
                                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
        if(v.size() >= 3) std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << '\n';
    }
}
```

```
$ g++ input.cpp -o loadavg.cpp
```

- **loadavg.py**

```py
with open('/proc/loadavg', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readline()

print(lines.split()[:3])
```

The benchmark is:

```
$ time (repeat 1000 eval './loadavg.cpp > /dev/null')
1.43s user 4.56s system 101% cpu 5.884 total

$ time (repeat 1000 eval './loadavg.sh > /dev/null')
3.30s user 11.95s system 102% cpu 14.884 total

$ time (repeat 1000 eval './loadavg.py > /dev/null')
40.76s user 14.79s system 97% cpu 57.257 total
```

So basically cpp is "only" 2x faster than bash and python is way slower.

I can expect that python is slower (even if too much, any ideas?), I was expecting cpp to be much faster.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You compiled without optimizations `(-O2)`. Don't benchmark code without optimizations.

Comment: The bottleneck is not going to be in your wrapper, which does nothing more than parse strings. It’s going to be in the system functions that you’re calling. It doesn’t matter which programming language you use.

Comment: You are only measuring the time to load a small C++, a medium awk and a quite huge python executable.

Comment: Even if I run `g++ -O2 input.cpp -o loadavg.cpp`, the result is `1.50s user 4.90s system 102% cpu 6.242 total`

Comment: Sidenote: You could simplify the c++ program further. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/zWgE_Z  and if you don't care about the `vector` you could copy directly to `std::cout`.